# Not able to build .net solution in Team city by using Nant.exe

Tags: build, teamcity, nant

I have using team city to build my project by using of Nant as build. So I have created one batch file in to build my project by where I using Nant.exe which is responsible for build my solution.

When I am ruing this batch file from command prompt I am successfully able to build my solution. But When I run the same file from TeamCity its giving me Build fail error.

So That I have verified path and that also correct. Below are the path I have stored in team city.

1. Path to a build file:  Build.bat (bat file for build)
2. Working directly : D:\CMS (path where my bat file is located.
3. NAnt home: Path were Nant exe located.
4. Targeted framwork : Net 4.0

When I am ruing this build by team city every time build fails with below log generated.

```
[21:27:54]: Checking for changes
[21:27:55]: Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[21:27:55]: Checkout directory: D:\Projects\JoyaCMS\src
[21:27:56]: Repository sources transferred
[21:27:55]: Updating sources: server side checkout... (1s)
[21:27:57]: Publishing internal artifacts (2s)
[21:27:57]: Starting: D:\Projects\JoyaCMS\src\UppercuT\lib\NAnt\NAnt.exe -      buildfile:D:\Projects\JoyaCMS\src\build.bat -targetframework:net-4.0 -  extension:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers   .dll -listener:JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NAntListener
[21:27:57]: in directory: D:\Projects\JoyaCMS\src
[21:27:57]: Process exited with code 1
[21:27:57]: NAnt output:
[21:27:57]: NAnt 0.91 (Build 0.91.3881.0; alpha2; 8/17/2010)
[21:27:57]: Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Gerry Shaw
[21:27:57]: http://nant.sourceforge.net
[21:27:57]: BUILD FAILED
[21:27:57]: For more information regarding the cause of the build failure, run the   build again in debug mode.
[21:27:57]: Try 'nant -help' for more information
[21:27:57]: D:\Projects\JoyaCMS\src\build.bat(1,1):
[21:27:57]: Error loading buildfile.
[21:27:57]: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
[21:28:02]: Publishing internal artifacts (1s)
[21:28:05]: Build finished
```

So let me know how can I resolve this issue in team city. and what setting I need to perform more to resolve this  issue.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

First of all I noticed a few occurrences of additional whitespace characters in your NAnt call e.g.`-  extension:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers   .dll`. Might be an SO formatting issue, but in case they're part of your batch, remove them first.

If this doesn't help, activate verbose build output via NAnt switch `-v+`. That should give more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I want to activate Verbose build output via NAnt then how can I achieve this? As I am new in Teamcity and NAnt so if you can provide me steps for that then that is really helpful to me.

Comment: add `-v+` as argument to your call to NAnt.exe